# Kotlin helper object class memory leak

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

I want to create a helper object that helps me to access strings from any where of project. Also this helper object should work in unit tests too. But I can not be sure that if is there any risk of memory leak for example usage ?

This is the helper object.

```
object ResourceHelper {

    private var getString: (Int) -> String = {
        it.toString()
    }

    private var getStringWithArgs: (Int, Array<out Any>) -> String = { id, args ->
        "$id${args.contentToString()}"
    }

    fun getString(@StringRes id: Int): String {
        return getString.invoke(id)
    }

    fun getString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg args: Any): String {
        return getStringWithArgs.invoke(id, args)
    }

    fun initialize(resources: Resources) {
        getString = { id -> resources.getString(id) }
        getStringWithArgs = { id, args -> resources.getString(id, *args) }
    }
}
```

This is the only activity in project.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        ResourceHelper.initialize(resources)
    }
}
```

This is the view model class, I do not have very detailed knowledge about how references is hold in stack. Is there any problem with this approach ?

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun printString(id: Int) {
        val s = ResourceHelper.getString(id)
        Log.d("*****", s)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Resources object from an Activity is different each time the Activity is started due to a configuration change.

Your code will temporarily leak the Resources object in between the times when the Activity is destroyed and the next time it is recreated (in `onCreate()` when you call `initialize()` again and overwrite which Resources object is being held by reference). If that's just the time during an orientation change, it's trivial. But if it's during the time between the user backing out of the Activity and the next time they return to the app, then your app will be hanging onto a little more memory than necessary.

State-holding singletons like this make unit testing difficult, anyway. I suggest creating extension functions as an alternative. If you need String resources access in a ViewModel, you can extend from AndroidViewModel, which has Resources access through the Application.

```
fun AndroidViewModel.getString(@StringRes id: Int) =
    getApplication<Application>().resources.getString(id)

fun AndroidViewModel.getString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg args: Any) =
    getApplication<Application>().resources.getString(id, args)
```

Comment: For the second case; backing out of the Activity and return to the app, will garbage collector be able to remove the old Resources reference. Isn't that old Resources overwritten by new Resources ?

Comment: During the time after the Activity is backed out of and the next time the user returns to the app, your singleton ResourceHelper object is still in memory and holding a reference to the Resources object, so the GC won't collect it. This is assuming the OS or the user doesn't kill your app in the meantime, which would clear all memory completely. The reason to avoid hanging onto more memory than you need is that it increases the likelihood of the OS killing your app when it needs to free memory, and a power user who actually looks closely enough might notice that your app is a memory hog.